# Moving VPN configuration from Juniper SSG5 to server

Tags: vpn, amazon-ec2

I have a VPN connection which is configured on our Juniper SSG5 and I need to move it to a server (since I can't add my own firewall to Amazon EC2). But I have not really an idea on how to do it or what to use.

Connection details:

- Remote VPN router: Cisco 3825 - IOS 12.4 (at `10.1.0.1`)
- IKE:

  - Main mode
  - AES256 - SHA1
  - PSK
  - DH group 5 (1536 bit)
  - SA lifetime: 86400s
- IPSec

  - ESP
  - AES256 - SHA1
  - PFS group: 5 (1536 bit modp)
  - SA lifetime: 3600 sec, lifesize: 4194303 KB
- Tunnels:

  - 10.1.0.80 (remote) - 10.2.0.104/29 (local)
  - 10.1.0.81 (remote) - 10.2.0.104/29 (local)

Note: it doesn't matter what runs on our side (OS or software). I was thinking of [StrongSWAN](http://strongswan.org) on Linux.

**Edit:**
All our servers (left side) will only communicate to our gateway and the gateway will communicate with `10.1.10.80`
[image: VPN config]

Comment: OK, just so this is straight, you have a system set up on the "local" end that talks to a "remote" network, and you are moving the "local" side to an Amazon EC2 instance?  Is the entire /29 being moved to Amazon, or will you just need one instance on Amazon's side to communicate with the "remote" servers?

Comment: @DerfK the entire local side is already on EC2, except for the VPN (and a proxy server that talks to the servers on the remote end). So it's only 1 server in `/29`, but the src-nat requires a `/29` (or else phase 2 of the VPN won't come up).

Comment: this sounds like what Amazon is selling Amazon VPC for... http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/

Comment: @DerfK when using [Amazon VPC](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/) I can't communicate with servers that aren't in the VPC.

Answer (score 0):

Have tou looked on FreeBSD? http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ipsec.html

Comment: FreeBSD doesn't run on EC2 yet (or at least not production ready according to http://www.daemonology.net/freebsd-on-ec2/)